# Stay on page after submit form

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

The goal is that once a the submit button is clicked, instead of going to send.php, it will just keep the page, I don't even want the page reloaded. If you guys have another way of doing this, that would be perfectly fine too.

My Ajax code

```
$("#sendtxt").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var phonenum = $("#phonenum").val();
        var provider = $("#provider").val();
        var message = $("#message").val();
        $.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            data : dataString,
            url : 'send.php',
            success : function(data) {
                alert(data);
            }
        });
    });
```

My Form code

```
    <form name="reqform" action="" method="post">
        <h1>Phone Number:
        <input name="phonenum" id="phonenum" type="text" class="txtbox-style" onkeyup="if (/\D/g.test(this.value)) this.value = this.value.replace(/\D/g,'')" required/>
        <select name = "provider" id ="provider" class="txtbox-style" required>
            <option value="@sms.mycricket.com">Cricket Wireless</option>
        </select>
        <br/>
        Message:
        <input name="message" id="message" type="text" class="txtbox-style"/>
        <br/>
        How many times?
        <input name="amount" id="amount" type="number" min="1" max="20" class="txtbox-style" required/>
        <br />
        <input type="submit" id="sendtxt" name="sendtxt" class="btn-style" value="Start Sending" />
        </h1>
    </form>
```

My send.php

```
<?php
 $to = $_POST["phonenum"];
 $provider = $_POST["provider"];
 $subject = 'Hi';
 $message = $_POST["message"];
 $headers = 'From: Hello' . phpversion();

 mail($to . $provider, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

Comment: I changed
<form name="reqform" action="" method="post"> to
<form name="reqform" action="send.php" method="post"> and it works but it takes me to the send.php page

Comment: Then your jQuery function isn't called at all, the submit would be prevented if it was called. Try to copy my entire answer and put it all at the end of your body. And put your form out of the h1 tag

Comment: So should I leave it as action="" or change it to action="send.php?

Comment: You can do there whatever you want, as as soon as your jQuery function is called, the form action is disabled. But it seems like jQuery isn't called at all. But from your actual code I can't know what the problem is. If the file isn't too long, post it in complete (the one with the form and the ajax function)

Comment: allright, take the scripts and cut and paste them to the end of your body, after the form

Comment: And you should put it all in a $(document).ready(function(){, see my edit

Comment: Holy hell. You did it. You are a genius. Any possible chance I could get you to explain why it matters where the script part is?

Comment: Because the div/form/button isn't loaded at the time when the jQuery function was called. You allways should put your scripts right before the closing </body> tag and wrap (most of) the functions in a document.ready

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data attribute wasn't correct, there was nothing being sent. You can try it like this, this will work:

You have to have jQuery included in your page, you can do this with this line and place it above your script:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $('input[name="phonenum"]').keyup(function(e) {
            if (/\D/g.test(this.value)) {
                // Filter non-digits from input value.
                this.value = this.value.replace(/\D/g, '');
            }
        });
        $("#sendtxt").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var phonenum = $("#phonenum").val();
            var provider = $("#provider").val();
            var message = $("#message").val();
            $.ajax({
                type : 'POST',
                data : {
                    provider : provider,
                    // ^key that appears in post
                    message : message,
                    // ^var you fetched before from the input
                    phonenum : phonenum
                },
                url : 'send.php',
                success : function(data) {
                    alert(data);
                    console.log('Success');

                },
                error : function(xhr, err) {
                    console.log("readyState: " + xhr.readyState + "\nstatus: " + xhr.status);
                    console.log("responseText: " + xhr.responseText);
                }
            });
        });
      });
    </script>
```

EDIT:

Check your console for errors (F12 in chrome), if there's an error, it will look like this, or similar:

[image]

If ajax succeeds, there will be at least "Success"

ANOTHER EDIT:

Put your form out of the `<h1>` tag, use it like this:

```
<h1>Phone Number:</h1>
```

and delete the `</h1>` at the end of your form...

Comment: Oh that makes a lot of sense. But for whatever reason, It's still not working =/
Is there a way to see error messages or something?

Comment: What is not working? @Dgameman1 Have a look in the console what it says ( F12 in your browser, then look for console)

Comment: The console stays blank :O

Comment: please try again, and check if the console says something now @Dgameman1 with the edited answer

Comment: The console is still blank :(

Comment: not possible. You have clicked the submit button, right?

Comment: Yes, and this is the code for it
<input type="submit" id="sendtxt" name="sendtxt" class="btn-style" value="Start Sending" />

Comment: There must be either 'Success' or some html code and an error code in the console after you've clicked the button. Do you have jQuery included in your page? @Dgameman1

Comment: When I put javascript:alert( "You are running jQuery version: " + $.fn.jquery ); into my address, par it says I'm running 1.11.1

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best Approach is to use the jquery `$.post` method

```
$("form").submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  $.post('send.php', $( this ).serialize()).done(function(data){
    alert(data);
  });

}
```

http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

** update **

example js fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/de71ju0r/1/

Comment: something wrong in your form `</h1>` before closing

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean @Amit, where do you see the issue?

Comment: check fiddle example, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Heading_Elements
`h1` tag shouldn't contain flow content...

Answer (score 0):

I prefer binding form's `submit` event (Because user may hit enter on focused `<input>` element, not submitting by clicking `<input type="submit">`), additionally there is an easier data colletion approach:

```
$("form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        data : $(this).serialize(),//Here we collect all entered data
        url : 'send.php',
        success : function(data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
});
```